# Cannot import skin with animation in hitfilm,is there anything we can do in Blender to prevent it?

Tags: animation

I'm new to Blender.

I tried animating a 3ds model and then importing it into hitfilm (https://hitfilm.com/)

Initial render looks pretty good in both cycles and blender internal, and also imports well as just 3d model, but when tryng the animation  everything "goes to bananas" (goes crazy) and skin disappears -_-

Comment: Try to write more than one sentence, try to use more than one comma and maybe start by explaining what "hitfilm" is. How does "everything go bananas"? What do you mean by skin?

Comment: @yann while I agree that the question is lacking a better shape and detailed content, how do you usually find about things on the internet? A simple "hitfilm" search shows you what it is as 1st result... (the same for "going bananas", although it doesn't explain _what_happens...)

Comment: @sadashiv jatti, as we know nothing about your models, and animation, try to describe (better adding a relevant picture of your scene, use the image button of the question editor) what you have, how you animated, etc. Try also to export (eg: to 3ds format) and then reimport it into blender. If it works well, it could be a hitfim issue, maybe it doesn't support certain features...

Comment: also I read on the website ""HitFilm supports the .lwo, .3ds and .obj formats." so try also other formats... (I would try obj)